# Eclipselink entity persist issue

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I am learning Eclipselink from some online tutorials. Currently facing an issue while persisting an object.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Exception
>   Description: No transaction is currently active   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.training.service.EmployeePersistance.main(EmployeePersistance.java:23)

My database connectivity using JPA connector is working fine. I have tested the connection by executing

```
System.out.println(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("_EclipseLinkTraining").isOpen());
```

which is returning true. Table is not created in DB. After executing the code, table is getting auto generated but object is not getting persisted. Following is my code which is causing trouble:
Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    int empId;

    @Basic(optional=true)
    String empName;

    //getters and setters
}
```

persistance.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="_EclipseLinkTraining" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.training.entity.Employee</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecpliselink_training"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

java main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("_EclipseLinkTraining");
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();

    manager.getTransaction();

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setEmpId(1);
    emp.setEmpName("sam");
    manager.persist(emp);

    manager.getTransaction().commit();

    manager.close();
    factory.close();
    System.out.println("completed");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the transaction, then committing it, but you've never [begun](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html#begin%28%29) it. So, as the message says, there is no transaction currently active.

Comment: Changed my code to 

manager.getTransaction().begin();

And it worked! You helped me second time since started using stackoverflow! Within few minutes and spot on solution. Thank you a lot.